# How do BigNums implementations work?

Tags: biginteger

I wanted to know how the BigInt and other such stuff are implemented. I tried to check out JAVA source code, but it was all Greek and Latin to me. 
Can you please explain me the algo in words - no code, so that i understand what i am actually using when i use something from the JAVA API.
regards

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Conceptually, the same way you do arbitrary size arithmentic by hand.  You have something like an array of values, and algorithms for the various operations that work on the array.

Say you want to add `100` to `901`.  You start with the two numbers as arrays:

```
 [0, 1, 0, 0]
 [0, 9, 0, 1]
```

When you add, your addition algorithm starts from the right, takes `0+1`, giving `1`, `0+0`, giving `0`, and -- now the tricky part -- `9+1` gives `10`, but now we need to carry, so we add 1 to the next column over, and put `(9+1)%10` into the third column.

When your numbers grow big enough -- greater than 9999 in this example -- then you have to allocate more space somehow.

This is, of course, somewhat simplified if you store the numbers in *reverse* order.

Real implementations use full words, so the modulus is really some large power of two, but the concept is the same.

There's a very good section on this in Knuth.

Comment: There is also a section in Numerical Recipes (which follows Knuth closely). The tricky part is to get the multiplication right. The school-algorithm doesn't scale very well, so you use tricks (eg. FFT). Once you have multiplication, you can express a lot of things with it.